# Call php function with variable that will be defined in the function

Tags: php

Maybe a strange title, but i have a situation where i want an output string (query, which can be any of length) to contain a variable that will be defined inside the function. Basically something like this, only i can't (as far as i know) call it as another argument because it's part of the query

```
function foo($var){
     $name = 'Name';
     echo($var);
}
```

[..]

foo('Hi my name is '.$name);

In my case a need to add the `id` of the last inserted row in a table, like

```
public function query($sql){
    foreach($sql AS $sqlString){
        if(!$db->exec($sqlString)){
            echo(self::throwError('MySql error',$sqlString,implode(":",$db->errorInfo())));
        }else{
            self::writeLog($table,$db->lastInsertId(),'update');
        }
        // Add this place i need some code to replace the $id from the call with the $db->lastInsertId() from the previous query
    }
}
[..]
$defaults->query(Array("
    INSERT INTO ".$table[1]." (m_id, m_title, m_link) VALUES ('','','".$val."')
","
    INSERT INTO ".$table[3]." (nmp_id, nmp_project_id, nmp_media_id) VALUES ('','".$_POST['p_id']."','".$id."')
"));
```

I'm out of options by now

Comment: I just don't get it..why do you want to it do this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could of course use placeholders in your queries that the function will replace:

```
'INSERT INTO ... %d'
```

then:

```
$sql = sprintf($sql, $id);
```

But it seems to me that overall your `query` function is doing too much and/or is confused about what its job is. It's too complex. Just make the `query` function execute one query with proper error handling and return the insert id, then call it twice:

```
$id = $defaults->query('INSERT ...');
$defaults->query("INSERT ... $id");
```

Comment: Whoah! That's it (your second suggestion) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, I'll give you a quick solution dough, although its a dirty solution.

```
    function foo($var) {
      global $name;
      $name = 'Name';
      echo($var);
    }
```

[..]

```
    foo('Hi my name is '.$name);
```

so notice that on the function, $name is declared as a global variable (instead of being a local variable to the method like $var)